# How to listen to a TCP port to detect changes in the server?

Tags: macos, sockets, cocoa, tcp

I'm working on mac os x. I'm trying to build a cocoa app working on a storage server (similar to Dropbox) that does something whenever a file is added,removed..I have already a client app installed on the mac that shows all the files stored on the server and I need to listen to the port that the server is using to send changes notification to the app. I've started following some tutorials for Sockets but I get "Address already in use".

The Question: are sockets the only way to listen to a port and if yes is there a way to build a socket to listen to an already existing server/client connection?

Answer (score 0):

If a process is already listening on a port then no other process can bind(2) to that port. Alternatives would include to have a proxy listen on that port that would deal with events and then pass them on elsewhere (the client app may not play well with this), or to use firewall rules to duplicate the packets to some other port that your app would then listen on, or maybe the client application issues notifications that then can be acted on.

https://github.com/thrig/lognots

Is one way to inspect the notifications available.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that listening on a port is how you prepare to receive incoming connections. It is *not* necessary to receive data — once a connection is established, data can flow in both directions! It is almost never appropriate for a client application to listen on a port; that's usually only appropriate for server applications.

With that in mind: Your client application should *connect* to a port on the server, and the server will send data to the client as appropriate.